# cannot find javax.swing.JPanel

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jpanel

I'm a novice in java coding.
Just downloaded the JDK 8 and Eclipse java ee ide.

eclipse cannot find JPanel.

the error says the JPanel has an access restriction.

how do I fix this?

here is my program

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class purcellm26try2 extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    }

}
```

I can rephrase my question if users don't understand.
Thank you

Comment: does Eclipse have any Installed JREs?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work in your case, but try re-configuring the buildpath. Right click on your project, go to `Build Path > Configure Build Path`. From there, remove the JRE System library that you see (under the Libraries tab). Click `Add Library` and choose `JRE System Library`. Select an `Alternate JRE`, and pick the JDK you want. EDIT: If your JDK8 doesn't appear for an alternate JRE, you might have to look for where you installed it, and manually add it. For that, just click `Installed JREs` and click `Add`. Choose the Standard VM (if you dont understand what it is), and find JDK8

Comment: Not related to your question but DON'T set the property of a component in the painting method. This will potentially cause a loop since changing the background of the component will cause it to automatically be repainted.

Comment: You're awesome! I was able to get this sorted out. Thank you for the help and I will check out your concern with the paintComponent.